# How can i call method on some interval of time using whenver gem in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

A method is written in model but I am not able to execute that method after some interval of time using whenever gem, below is my code :-

**stage.rb (model)**

```
def check_project_activity
  // code here
end
```

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.day, at: '4:30 am' do
    runner "Stage.check_project_activity"
 end
```

method call generate error but calling this method through terminal works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the instance method `check_project_activity` as if it's class method.

If your logic doesn't depend on the instance, make it class method

```
def self.check_project_activity
  // code here
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're showing an instance method, which is to say you can only call `check_project_activity` on a specific stage instance.

Maybe you want to check project activity on all projects?

In which case in the model you'd have

```
def self.check_all_stages_project_activity
  all.each do |stage|
    stage.check_project_activity
  end
end
```

And in your `schedule_rb` you'd have

```
every 1.day, at: '4:30 am' do
  runner "Stage.check_all_stages_project_ativity"
ed
```